# Why doesn't the (ionChange) event hit in Ionic4?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a dropdown list and everytime the value is changed I want the method `ionChangeClicked()` to hit.

Here is the html code:

```
<ion-label position="floating"><ion-icon style= "color : white" name="git-branch-outline"></ion-icon><a>Division</a></ion-label>
  <ion-select id="yourDivision" style= "color : white" (ionChange)=" ionChangeClicked();" [(ngModel)] = "branchSelected" placeholder = {{this.myService.getBranchName()}}> 
    <ion-select-option id="yourDivision" class="radiobutt" *ngFor="let branch of arrBranches" value={{branch.id}} selected="branchSelected">
      {{branch.name}}
    </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
```

And here is the method that is supposed to fire

```
ionChangeClicked(){
  console.log('Hit');
}
```

The problem is that it hits the first time but when I change the value a second time it doesnt hit.

Comment: It's unclear. There's a lot of messy code. You have a lot of spacing in your html that shoundn't be there, all your `<ion-select-option>` elements have the same id, it makes no sense to use `selected` attribute on every one of your options. Plus we have no idea what the value of `branchSelected` is. Clean up your code and post more of it.

Comment: I will post more specifics and cleaner code later today. The ``id="yourDivision"`` is only used to refresh the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet.

```
<ion-label position="floating"><ion-icon style="color:white" name="git-branch-outline"></ion-icon><a>Division</a></ion-label>
  <ion-select id="yourDivision" style="color:white" (ionChange)="ionChangeClicked()" [(ngModel)]="branchSelected" placeholder="{{ this.myService.getBranchName() }}"> 
    <ion-select-option id="option-{{i}}" class="radiobutt" *ngFor="let branch of arrBranches; let i = index" [value]="branch.id">
      {{ branch.name }}
    </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
```

As Wesley said, there are a lot of inconsistencies with your code. Try to spot the differences and you'll see.